# Is it possible to push a view controller without navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

i've just started to write an application and i want to write it without navigation controller thereis going to be some viewController EX: aviewController , bviewController ...

Is it possible to push to b class's view controller (bviewController) from aViewController wiyhout using navigation controller ?

With otherwords ,

are there any different option for this code :

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.bViewController animated:YES];`   ???

Comment: What do you mean by "push A to B without a navigation controller"? What kind of strange UI behavior are you designing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a UINavigationController and push it, and hide the navigationbar.

Comment: Not helpful - links, advice, reasons why this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this maybe?

```
    [self.bViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: He is asking to do it without a navigationcontroller.

Comment: Why is this such a bad idea. I quote: "possible to push to b class's view controller (bviewController) from aViewController". No one will ever see the navigation bar, but the functionality remains the same. Really necessary for -1? @rckoenes The question remains vague.

Comment: @rckoenes - we should tell him that he _should_ be using a navigation controller. @Schoob - you got voted down because you answer didn't explain what you meant very well.

Comment: @deanWombourne True, you should use a navigationcontroller, but whe the ask to do it without who am I to tell you diffent. But ya the correct answer should be why don't you want to use the navigation controller.

Comment: _'who am I to tell you different'_ - you're the person he's asked for advice :) - Have a read of this http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx to see why I'd question him instead of just answering!

Comment: @deanWombourne, Read the post and have changed my mind. I will educate from now on.

Answer (score 2):

You display a Modal view:

```
 [self presentModalViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

The transition animation is set on the viewcontroller that you are going to display.

As @deanWombourne stated below, why don't you wan't to use the Navigation controller? If you are pushing viewcontrollers then the navigation controller is the way to go.

If you don't want the navigationbar you can just hide it and pop the view controller your self:

```
// Remove the current visible view controller:
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: i thoudht that i should navigation controllers for all classes to the main window so i asked this question but i saw that its not neccessary one navigation controller is enough so its ok for me now thank you but anyway i still wonder if it is possible or not ?

Comment: In my mind this is the correct answer - it answers the users (and my!) question without suggesting a major change to the project.