# How to call perform segue method from another class?

Tags: swift, xcode7, segue

I want to perform segue from **View B** to **View C** and I am calling method in **class A**.
My segue method in Class B is-

```
//ViewController B


func nextViewAction() -> Void  {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("nextview", sender: self)
    }
```

And I am calling it in Class A like this-

```
//ViewController A



@IBAction func sideMenuAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        ViewClassB().nextViewAction()
}
```

[image]

**But it crashing-**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'nextview''

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the name `nextview` for the segue between Controller B and Controller C? You can check by clicking on the segue between the two controllers, and then checking the **Identifier** value in the **Attributes Inspector**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, its same. **nextview**

Comment: Are you able to share the project with me so that I can take a look to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

What you can have is move to the third viewcontroller from first viewcontroller by skipping the second one use the code below..

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var viewControllerToInsertBelow : UIViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.delegate = self
}

func pushTwoViewControllers() {
    if let viewController2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id1"),
        let viewController3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("id2") { //change this to your identifiers
            self.viewControllerToInsertBelow = viewController2
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController3, animated: true)
    }
}

//MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if let vc = viewControllerToInsertBelow {
        viewControllerToInsertBelow = nil
        let index = navigationController.viewControllers.indexOf(viewController)!
        navigationController.viewControllers.insert(vc, atIndex: index)
    }
}
```

}

Reference : [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135273/skip-add-a-view-controller-in-navigation-stack)

Comment: keep remember, I am not using  `UINavigationController` at all

Comment: please read [Is it possible to push a view controller without navigation controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290097/is-it-possible-to-push-a-view-controller-without-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to do any other code just use 
notification observer it will solve your problem.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot trigger segue action from AViewController because what
    performSegue does is  that :

```
Initiates the segue with the specified identifier from the current view controller's storyboard file.
```

Try implementing segue from A to C